# How to make a Visual studio 2015 website Installer for my client?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, installation, web-deployment

I have developed a website in visual studio for my client. Now, I need to deliver it to him. I know I can publish the app directly to his web server but that's not what he wants. He wants me to provide all the code in a form of installer so that he can deploy the application on his own. 
Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: What about this issue in your side? Maybe you could think about using the WIX installer for your web app: https://alonam.com/blog/2016/09/14/creating_a_wix_installer_for_asp.net_web_applications.html and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application

Answer (score 0):

haha,
zip and send it ;) tell him unzip it where he wants! charge for IIS setup instructions ;)

Comment: I like the part "charge for the IIS instructions"

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about docker?
For ASP.net core you can use standard docker images and for the old fashioned ones windows containers - they require windows 10 at you client to get run.
Here is a documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc

Btw. delivering .net core mvc applications is easier than the oldfashioned ones. They don't require an IIS (but can get run behind it).

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use Installshield, advanced installer or wix installer. Deploy tomcat, iis or another web server technology through this installer as a prereq or as part of the actual application. When he runs the setup.exe installer, it should install the web server technology, and place your application files on the root directory.